# in-line math equation rendering/preview for macvim/vim for filetypes other than RMarkdown

Tags: filetype, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

I recently installed vim-rmarkdown package, and found that the package allows me to see the rendered math equation in macvim, and when move cursor over, the line will render back to latex equation symbols and allows me to edit further. I want to know if this convenient math equation rendering in macvim is available in a package for other filetypes other than RMarkdown files?

This is when I can see the rendered `\theta` inline :

[image: rendered]

When move cursor to the line, I can see `\theta` as usual in tex files:

[image: rendered back]